# Android TV how to make a tab on the top of screen?

Tags: tabs, android-tv

I want to make a tab on the top of screen like this :

[image]

I know that tabLayout and viewPager can solve it on the phone. However, how to do on the android tv?

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways you could do this - but I think the short answer is no matter what you do, it'll have to be custom. So far `leanback` is the only framework offered by Google for any TV specific components and that framework only provides you with a left navigational drawer.

I can offer one solution for if you're using leanback. You could use a `BrowseFragment` with a custom `TitleView` which has tabs and keeps track of the focus of the tabs within. As long as your custom view implements `TitleViewAdapter.Provider` then you can use it with a `BrowseFragment` as the `TitleView`. The benefit to this is that you can have it automatically animate in and out from the top with little additional work.

As for the custom view, you can specify focusRight and focusLeft on each tab and have an listener `onFocus` or `onClick` to swap out the fragments in the `BrowseFragment`. [This class in leanback](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java) shows how to swap fragments in the `BrowseFragment` (specifically `PageRowFragmentFactory`).

I would highly recommend you clone the [leanback showcase app](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase) that the Android team put together and play around in that.

For the specifics of customizing the TitleView, it'll look something like the below:

---

Create your custom view

```
class YourTitleView extends RelativeLayout implements TitleViewAdapter.Provider {
    ... do custom view setup/logic here ...
}
```

Create an XML file named `lb_browse_title.xml`. This overrides leanback's layout which they use to create their TitleView.

Put your title view in this `lb_browse_title.xml` file and ensure it has the id of `@+id/browse_title_group`. This is so leanback knows to grab your title view.

```
<com.your.android.app.views.YourTitleView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/browse_title_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?attr/browseTitleViewStyle" />
```

Then create a Fragment that extends `BrowseFragment` and it should apply your title view automatically. Please refer to the `leanback-showcase` app for how to get a `BrowseFragment` up and running.